# Adding Application Menu to gnome-dashboard

Tags: linux

Is there a way to display the gnome-application menu to gnome-dashboard. I accidentally broke the left side screen of my laptop and unable to access gnome-application menu. So can I add gnome-application menu to gnome-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, Settings.  If not Ubuntu, Gnome settings. Then Appearance.  The application bar can be placed left, bottom or right. That should help you with your screen issue.

Once done, you can add applications to the menu bar.

You may need to get to Settings by Command line:

gnome-control-center